# Autocomplete Google Map V3 Places impossible to customize?

Tags: google-maps, autocomplete, google-geocoder

I narrowed autocomplete to a region and to a bounds that cover only Australia, but I am still receving autocomplete with Chile and China and other country out of the selected area.
Does anyone have a good solution to work this problem?
I also can't change the styling off Google autocomplete, it is a self generated Div with style tag that overcomes my style to autocomplete DIV?
I started to use Geocoder and Jquery autocomplete to filter the results but it doesn't work as well as Google Autocomplete the results are less than google maps autocomplete?

I call the Library like this:

Here is the code of creating the auto complete:

```
    var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(-47.5765257137462, 106.259765625),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-9.6, 179.359375));

    var options = {
      bounds: defaultBounds,
      types: ['geocode'],
      offset: 5
    };

    var input = document.getElementById('store-locator-header');

    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input,options);
```

Answer (score 4):

Nowadays, you can restrict to a country with:

componentRestrictions: {country: 'us'},

Answer (score 2):

When [Adding Autocomplete](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/places.html#adding_autocomplete) with `bounds`, *results are **biased** towards, but **not restricted** to, Places contained within these bounds.* This is the same as when using [Viewport Biasing](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Viewports) in the [Geocoding API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding). I'm afraid I don't have a method to filter out those suggestions that fall outside of the `bounds`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to qucikly customise can be to set component restriction like shown below

```
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
//autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);//restrict to bounds or viewport
autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions({'country': 'uk'});//restrict to country
```

more about places biasing [here](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete#location_biasing)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that [LatLngBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#LatLngBounds) expects south-west and north-east corners.

Instead of:

```
var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(-47.5765257137462, 106.259765625),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-9.6, 179.359375));
```

It should be:

```
var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(-9.6, 106.259765625),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-47.5765257137462, 179.359375));
```

---

There is actually [documentation to style the UI elements of Autocomplete](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#style_autocomplete).